# Magento 2 Extension missing on Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, extensions

Magento 2 Extension missing on Admin
My Magento 2 shop used to have this extension named FME Price Calculator but for some reason the extension no longer appears on the Admin menu.

I noticed that all the extensions folders can be seen on /magento2/app/code , including the FME folder with a Pricecalculator folder in it, so why is the extension not showing on Admin?

Comment: You can check if the module is enabled/disabled. Check in `app/etc/config.php` or run this command from magento root: `bin/magento module:status NameSpace_ModuleName`

Comment: There is not even a registration.php in the Pricecalculator folder, so the model doesn't exist I think. Only thing that's on that folder is an Index.php with some code. So I guess it makes sense why it's not showing but I don't understand how it used to be there before.